# Proving if $A$ is a countable set then the quitent group $A/R$ is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove/disprove: if $A$ is a countable set then the quotient group $A/R$ is countable. $R$ is an equivalence relation.

I think it's not true, since every equvilance class is a subset of $A$, then the quotient group is like the set of all subsets of $A$. So a counter example could be: $|\mathbb N |=\aleph_0\le \mathcal P(\mathbb N)=\mathcal C$

Comment: If $\mathcal{P}$ is a partition on $A$ then countability of $A$
implies countability of $\mathcal{P}$. Is that clear for you?

Comment: @drhab, please explain.

Comment: Every equivalence relation on $A$ corresponds with a partition of $A$. The sets in this partition are the equivalenceclasses. Countability of $A/R$ is exactly the same thing as countability of this partition. In fact the partition can be identified with $A/R$. So if you can prove what I said in my first comment then you are ready. Visualizing set $A$ and partitioning it can help you in understanding why this is true.

Comment: @drhab So the quotient group is basically the set of representatives of each partition, is that right ?

Comment: $A/R=\left\{ \left[a\right]_{R}\mid a\in A\right\} $ where $\left[a\right]_{R}$
denotes the equivalenceclass represented by $a$.

Comment: Here $a\mapsto\left[a\right]_{R}$ is a surjection $A\rightarrow A/R$
and choosing for each element of $A/R$ some representative results
in an injection $A/R\rightarrow A$. See the answers of Asaf and Rasmus.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** There is a surjection from $A$ onto $A/R$. What can be the cardinality of the image of a function with a countable domain?

Comment: $\aleph_0$ at most. Why there's a surjection ?

Comment: Think about it more than five minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You have a surjective map $A\to A/R$.  Alternatively, you can choose an injective map $A/R\to A$.  These should help you show that the statement you are trying to prove or disprove is, in fact, true.